# Symfony render multiple objects

Tags: php, symfony

i'd like to render some film details on a page, as well as a button to delete the film.
However, i don't know how to send multiple response to my twig page.
Here is my code :

````php
    public function show( ManagerRegistry $doctrine, $id): Response {
        $film = $doctrine->getRepository(Film::class)->find($id);

          $builder 
             ->add('deleteFilm', ButtonType::class) 
          ;

        return $this->render('details/description.html.twig', ['film' => $film]);

    }
    ```
but as you can see, i can only render, my film object but not my button. How can i do that ? 
Thanks for your help
````

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Where did the $builder variable come from? Are you sending a FormView (`$form->createView()`) to the twig template?

Comment: no, the thing is, i'm a very beginner in symfony and i don't know how to create a button, and the symfony documentation was very unclear about that.

Answer (score 1):

So quick update here, i finally solved my problem.
my misunderstanding was that it's possible to send multiple objects to the twig template.
So that's my final code :

```php
   class descriptionFilm extends AbstractController{
     /**
     * @Route("/details/{id}", name="description")
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     */


    public function show( ManagerRegistry $doctrine, $id, Request $request): Response {
        $film = $doctrine->getRepository(Film::class)->find($id);

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
             ->add('submitForm', SubmitType::class, ['label'=>'delete film '])
             ->getForm()
        ; 

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
//Do some stuff here

            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }

        $form ->handleRequest($request);

   

        return $this->render('details/description.html.twig', ['film' => $film, 'deleteFilm' => $form->createView()]);


    }
```